# Save currently opened file

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on a script that allows the user to edit the page he's viewing and then copy all the resulting HTML inside of the clipboard.

However, I would like to improve that system in order to directly save the file you're working on as if you were editing it in your text editor software.

The use case is what follows:
I'm opening a local file with the `file:///` protocol.
I trigger my script which adds contenteditable to the HTML tag.
When I'm done editing the content, I trigger my script again.
It proceeds to remove the contenteditable attribute from the HTML tag and then copies all the HTML of the page inside the clipboard.

It's useful because I have a same template for several newsletter files and I don't want to have to dive into the HTML just to change some bindings and all.

However, I think it would be a great improvement if the file would save itself when I trigger my script the second time.

I've been looking at some solutions but nothing quite seems to allow me to save a file to a specific location.

Do you have any idea on how I could achieve that ?

Thanks in advance,

P.S. : My solution is 100% javascript.

Comment: Can you imagine the chaos if websites could write to your local filesystem? Best you can do is offer a download function.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you, but in my case it's specifically to work on a local file (opened with file:/// protocol). So I hoped there would be a specific behavior.

Comment: You can't save a file to a specific location using purely client-side code. You need server-side thing to do it. Although in your case "server" will be the same machine but still - same idea will apply. You might be better of just editing the page and then hitting Ctrl + S to save it via the browser (it should give you a prompt for "where do you want this saved").

Comment: @PatrickEvans extensions allow you to write to the user system ?